# CSS or other bug in rendering page?

Tags: support, fonts, rendering

Anyone else get screen rendering issues like me?  Firefox for Windows 3.5.2

Screenshot: http://www.flickr.com/photos/10105277@N00/3838846646/sizes/o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the default font for you is quite a bit larger than it should be (width wise).

Which fonts from the below do you have?
`Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New`

Comment: Can't remember. It works well now.